# SELECT NEW in Spring data JPA 1.10

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I'm trying to upgrade my environment to 1.10.2.RELEASE, currently we're on 1.9.4.RELEASE and everything works. but after upgrade my HQL failed
on **ResultTransformer is not allowed for 'select new' queries.**
Now i use select new to contract non manged entitis and i use fully qualified class name in the select statement.
Any ideas how we can solve this issue?

Comment: Quite a few bugs in that area have been fixed for 1.10.2 actually. Any chance you post the complete stack trace as well as the query and cause that's causing the issue?

Comment: I have the same problem on 1.20.2. This is my query:`select distinct new com.acme.ClauseGroupProductName(g.id, p.id, t.language, t.text) 
    from Product p 
         inner join p.productClauses pc 
         inner join pc.clause pcc 
         inner join pcc.clauseGroups g 
         inner join p.names pn 
         inner join pn.texts t`